# Ext 2 prevent ComboBox from Store loading

Tags: extjs, combobox, store, extjs2

According to the most recent [Ext JS documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) I have to set `queryMode: 'local'` in `ComboBox` configuration to prevent it from autoloading its `Store` (I want to load the content of this Store manually, after selecting the value in another `ComboBox`, and do some filtration of records).
The issue it that we're still using the Ext JS version 2.2, and I didn't find this option in [docs](http://extjs.edspencer.net/extjs/docs/#Ext.form.ComboBox). So, the question is: how I can achieve the same `ComboBox`'s behavior in the old Ext JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. The configuration option is already there, the only difference between Ext 4 and Ext 2 is that the name of this option isn't `queryMode`, but `mode`. I had to be more thoughtful.